# Macro for Setting X axis to cross the Y Axis based on a cell value

Tags: axes

I am looking to set the x axis to cross the y axis based on a value in a cell.  Is there a macro I can use to accomplish this?

Thanks,  Natalie

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in case anyone is curious:

```
Sub Set_Analyst_Medians()
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 23").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisShow)
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 23").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = Range("D38")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Range("D49")
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Range("D50")
Selection.Delete
End Sub
```